# Unexpected error when querying Google Play Developer API. Please check if you use a correct service account

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-billing, play-billing-library, billingclient

I am implementing [Android Billing client Library V 3.0](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples) . In Billing Client v 3.0 you have to use [backend server for subscription states handling](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer). For that purpose you have to link your google cloud account with your play console account.
So I have created service account and linked it with Google Play Console. I have given the permission of Released Manager.
Now the issue i am facing is that, when google cloud query to play console through cloud function of my firebase server, it says that " **Unexpected error when querying Google Play Developer API. Please check if you use a correct service account** " and
"**The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation**"
One solution ("https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/350") for this problem was that i have seen on stacker overflow and suggested by google member is that "I have to wait for 24-48 hours after linking service account to play console and granting access."
I have waited for 4 days but this solution does't worked for me.

I'll be really thank full if someone has the solution related to my problem.
Thank you.

#android-studio #billingclient_V3.0 #android #play-blling-library #in-app-billing

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add scope ".../auth/androidpublisher" in Google cloud console.
after adding scope you have to wait for 24 hours and then you can start working with it.
After you add scope you should save credentials at the bottom of page.

Comment: Ajmal, I am facing a similar issue, but the error I get is "Unexpected error when querying Google Play Developer API. Please check if you use a correct service account" and "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console". I have double checked every single step but I just can't get around this error. Any help from your own experience on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ~A

Comment: After updating the scope, try updating any in-app or subscription item, no need to wait for 24 hours.